# Podfile not downloading the latest versions of pods

Tags: cocoapods, optimizely

I am using cocoapods for my company project and I am having an issue regarding getting the latest pods.

In my Podfile, I have many pods but my pain point is the optimizely pod.

**pod 'Optimizely-iOS-SDK'** - this should get the latest pod version but it doesn't. The latest version is 1.2.2 but this gets 1.0.78.

When I make a specific version pod:
**pod 'Optimizely-iOS-SDK', '1.2.2'**
This complains:

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- `Optimizely-iOS-SDK (= 1.2.2)` required by `Podfile`

Cocoapods version: 0.39.0

OS X: El Capitan

Ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p645

I would appreciate any pointers as to what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

**EDIT**: My main problem is that without mentioning any version number why is it getting the older (1.0.78) version and not the latest version?

**Update**: pod install --verbose

-> Installing Optimizely-iOS-SDK (1.0.78)

> Git download
>   Git download
>        $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/optimizely/Optimizely-iOS-SDK.git
>        /var/folders/n7/tr3hj67d0gxbdbm2thmsrr840000gp/T/d20151014-1032-jwurwk --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 1.0.78
>        Cloning into '/var/folders/n7/tr3hj67d0gxbdbm2thmsrr840000gp/T/d20151014-1032-jwurwk'...
>        error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200

[!] Error installing Optimizely-iOS-SDK
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/optimizely/Optimizely-iOS-SDK.git /var/folders/n7/tr3hj67d0gxbdbm2thmsrr840000gp/T/d20151014-1032-jwurwk --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 1.0.78

Cloning into '/var/folders/n7/tr3hj67d0gxbdbm2thmsrr840000gp/T/d20151014-1032-jwurwk'...

error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200

Comment: Is the `'source'` field in your Podfile correct? It should be - `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`

Comment: yeah. the source is exactly the same.

Answer (score 5):

Try using this command

```
pod install --repo-update
```

or

```
pod repo update
pod install
```

The new version of pod not updates the repo when `pod install` is executed

Comment: can someone explain why this works. I completely uninstalled the using `pod deintegrate` and then tried pod install again it did not work. Even explicitly specifying the newest version gave me an error saying this version does not exist and giving me a hint to use `pod install --repo-update` so what gives ? How to completely remove an old version of the pod on my machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Tryed removing completely cocoapods and installing again?

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
sudo pod install
sudo pod update
```

I got similiar error after updating to new version of Xcode. This helped me. Commands wrote by memory - but the flow should be right.

Comment: I have tried them all with no result. I have tried installing specific versions of cocoapods as well and that didn't help as well.

Answer (score 0):

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements: - Optimizely-iOS-SDK
>   (= 1.2.2) required by Podfile

This error could possibly be related to a minimum deployment target issue. Which ios platform is defined at the top of your Podfile? (e.g. platform :ios, '9.0'). Looking at their [GitHub page](https://github.com/optimizely/Optimizely-iOS-SDK), Optimizely-iOS-SDK v1.2.2 supports build targets for iOS 7 and above.